# Creating summary and table in an R Shiny database

Tags: r, shiny

I am having trouble creating a reactive function for my table and the summary also won't show up. Basically, I want the table to list the number of observations the user chooses on the side panel. The code i have used to create the table and summary must be wrong

[Image of the code I have used to create R shiny database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMQxk.png)

Comment: Don't post you code a images. Try to provide a minimal reproducible example of your problem. Otherwise you will get downvotes and no answers to this question.

Comment: This is because your reactive function only refers ti dataset choice not the number of obs. Try returning `head(data, n=input$obs)` instead of simply `data`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your desired output, but here is an app that can be useful for you. It let you pick a dataframe and show a variable number of rows.

```
library(shiny)
data <- list(mtcars = mtcars, iris = iris)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput('dataset', 'Dataset', choices = c("mtcars", "iris")),
  numericInput("nrow", "Number of rows", value = 10, min = 0),
  tableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$table <- renderTable({
    head(data[[input$dataset]], input$nrow) 
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]